# Keychain in IOS

Tags: iphone

please, can someone tell me in a few words whats is keychain ? what's based for ? or shrare e document where i can understand,

thanks

Comment: is your search engine broken?

Comment: [Related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558252/ios-keychain-security)

Answer (score 2):

Keychain is not specifically an iOS feature. It's Mac OS's password management system.  More info

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keychain_(Mac_OS)