# Protect Data distributed with iPhone application

Tags: ios, iphone, ssl, encryption

I have an iPhone application that talks to a web service over SSL. I would like to distribute a key with the app which the app can use to identify itself to the web service (An application key). All apps can use the same key, so I can distribute the same key with every app.

How can I distribute this in a way that protects it from discovery or use by anything other than the application?

I am using Core Data with a SQLite db.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the iOS keychain mechanism. Google for that for more info, or get a look at [`SFHFKeychainUtils`](https://github.com/ldandersen/scifihifi-iphone/tree/master/security), which is a small class by Buzz Andersen that makes handling the key chain very easy.

If you are concerned about the "real" security offered by the iOS keychain, have a read at [this very interesting S.O. article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558252/ios-keychain-security).

Comment: Thanks. So I can distribute the key securely with the application and then access it from within the application?

Comment: That is what the keychain is meant for... it is just like the MacOS keychain, every sensible piece of info (passwords, certs, etc) are stored there...

Comment: So I can store a password securely once the application is installed, but how would I protect the password when I distribute it? I would need to store the password in the app bundle until the application first runs and can add it to Keychain. During this time it is exposed.